# Deleting post doesn't seems to be doing right. Why?

Tags: discussion

**Posts, mostly from new users, that are VLQ and/or not-an-answer, thus are good for deletion and hence are deleted.**

That should be the case. *But* this doesn't seems to be conveying the author the message as to why that post was deleted. Especially in the case of answers which don't have the on-hold and closed phase.

Since such deletions are not brought into the authors notice, (s)he wouldn't even realize whether a particular post of his/her was deleted and why. What standards we are seeking on this site they'll never know. They'll have to learn it the hard way after many iterations.

Why so lenient? Educate them and make them realize that this is not the *regular* Islamic forum which they are used to.

What action do I propose? Before deletion, of non-offensive and/or non-spam, objectively and constructively tell the author what's not right about their post, lead them to relevant meta discussion and advice them to revise. And if unheeded then we should be left with no other choice but to delete. Same is for the flaggers and moderators.

I realize that this would be time consume and require more effort. But the advantages of it are most likely quite higher.

Comment: I always leave a comment before deleting explaining the reason behind it.

Comment: Ahh. And the rep under-[privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) were keeping them away from sight.

Comment: @Ansari But one thing. If the comment is deleted or moved to the comments section, then it doesn't give the answerer an opportunity to improvise. Worth mentioning I have mostly seen those which are completely off-the-mark being deleted or moved.

Comment: Yeah if there's really no way an answer can be improved I delete it. If there's some seed of a good answer, it's left alone. Regardless I invite them to submit another answer if they so feel inclined.